# How to clean and frame an autographed jersey?

Tags: nhl, maintenance, uniform, collectibles

I recently bought my dad an autographed Colorado Avalanche jersey for his birthday. I am wondering what the next steps are with the jersey to get it cleaned and framed. Are there places that handle this sort of thing? Can I do it myself?

Answer (score 3):

I found a very useful [**link (CardBoardConnection)**](https://www.cardboardconnection.com/how-frame-jersey) that can help you with the frame. There, you have a step by step "How to Frame a Jersey":

> 1. Measure your jersey to pick the right sized frame. Most jerseys will fit in either a 30" x 36" or 32" x 40" frame.
> 2. Lay the jersey out in the desired position (and orientation to the frame) on the matte backing board inside the shadow box frame or foam
>      board if using a standard frame.
> 3. Fold and iron the uniform so that the player name, number and sleeve patch logos are visible.
> 4. Iron the jersey on the folds.
> 5. Temporarily pin the uniform to backing using stainless steel framing pins. Stainless steel pins are ideal as they will not rust or
>      discolor. They will also not damage the jersey fabric.
> 6. Stitch the jersey to the mat board with needle and thread. Stitching areas include; below the neckline, at the start of each
>      sleeve, and at the bottom hem. Be sure the thread goes through the
>      back of the jersey so it doesn't show. Knot the ends of the thread
>      behind the backboard and tape them down to the back of the matte to
>      hold them securely.
> 7. Close the shadow box and hang proudly. If you are using a traditional frame follow these additional steps before hanging:
> 8. Remove the protective film from one side of the Plexiglass. Lay that side down firmly on top of the jersey. Once it is aligned
>      straight, peel the film from the other side of the Plexiglass. Attach
>      the sides of the frame. Many frames will simply click together, you
>      may have to use special mounting brackets and clips to properly secure
>      the frame.

About the cleaning, i advise you to watch [**THIS**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzYkxmtb3nw) youtube video.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I have found several good websites to look at
The first is the one stated above, and there is no need stating it again. The second one is on wikihow, and is fairly good. ( In my opinion do not wash the jersey, it may dull the signature)

> 2: Select a backing. Unlike with a regular picture frame, the backing that comes with your shadow box may not be all you need to use for your framing project. For a jersey, typically you need foam backing to provide support (this might come in the frame), and an acid-free archival backing paper to go over the top. You may or may not choose to use matting around the edges for extra effect.[2]
>   A lot of framers choose to use dry mounting to prepare the backing for the frame. This safely attaches the archival paper to the backboard.
>   The backing paper should be a neutral color that complements your jersey.
>
> 3: Get the rest of your supplies. For completing your project, you’ll also need a measuring tape, an x-acto knife, a sewing needle (embroidery works best), clear thread (like fishing line), and whatever mounting materials you chose to use (specific to the type of backing you’re using). You’ll probably also want a clothing iron, so that you can prepare your jersey for framing and help the folds to lie flat inside the frame.
>
> Part 2:
>
> 1: Prepare your backing. Cut your foam or backing board to shape, using an x-acto knife. The board should be the same size as your frame. Then, place your mounting paper over the top. If you’re dry mounting the backing, you should do so now.
>
> 2: Cut your foam board insert. If you have enough room inside the shadow box frame, it is a nice addition to insert a sheet of foam inside the jersey, inside the frame. This will provide support and help the jersey to look a bit more filled-out than if you pin it flat to the board. Cut a piece of your foam board into a rectangle the size of the torso of the jersey, and insert it inside. You can sew the backside of the jersey to the board to help secure it in place, or just use a few straight pins.
>
> 3: Fold your jersey. Although there are a few different ways to fold your jersey, they all are done so that the major logos and symbols are visible inside the frame. Lay your jersey flat on a tabletop, and fold the sleeves over so that they go downwards. Use an iron to keep the jersey in this position, to prepare it for its life in a frame.

Again, this was from wikihow, and I will put the link for it below, if you need it.
Personally, I would not sow the jersey into the backing, because you could not take the jersey out again. There is a whole part, although it may be unnecessary, it is about picking the best frame, and there is two parts about finishing it up, and sewing the jersey in place, if you so choose

https://www.wikihow.com/Frame-a-Jersey